# Prove that there is no simple graph G with 6 vertices that is isomorphic with G'.

Tags: graph-theory

One of the possible answers is:

Two isomorphic graphs must have the same number of edges. The **total number of possible edges**, using the formula [n(n-1)/2] where n is the number of vertices, **must be even, so that the graph and its complement can have the same number of edges.** G has 6 vertices and its total number of possible edges is 15, which is not even. Hence, there is no simple graph G with 6 vertices that is isomorphic with G’.

My question is: why must the number of edges be even?  How does that make a graph and its complement have the same number of edges?

Comment: I think you're misreading the argument slightly. Consider the total number of edges in $K_6$; _that_ number is 15. Now, if $G$ is a graph isomorphic to $K_6-G$ with $n$ edges, then how many edges does $K_6-G$ have? How many edges would that mean that $K_6$ has?

Comment: Right, the number of edges in $K_6$ is not even (it is $15$), but the number of edges ($E$) of $G$ plus the number of edges ($E^\prime$) of $G^\prime$ must be even, $E+E^\prime = 2E,$ so $G$ is not isomorphic to $G^\prime$.